# How to pass Arduino struct to Raspberry Pi via i2c?

Tags: arduino, i2c

For my Arduino, I have a struct:

```
int temp;

struct dataStruct {
   int Data;          
   int Data2;
   int Data3;
   int Data4;
   int Data5;
} my; 

void setup() {
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveData);
    Wire.onRequest(sendData);
}

void loop(){
    delay(1000)
}

void receiveData(){
    while(Wire.available){
        temp = Wire.read();
    }
}

void sendData(){
    Wire.write((byte *)&my, sizeof(my));
}
```

And I want to pass the struct to my Raspberry Pi through i2c via the Wire.write function. I realize that simply trying Wire.write(my); will not work so I am wondering if there is a way I can go about doing this? Maybe I need to try a whole other method altogether? I am willing to try other ways as long as I can get the struct transmitted to the Raspberry Pi.

Here is my Python code as well:

```
import socket
import os
import random
import time
import smbus
import struct
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

temp = bytes([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00])
the_struct = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

def writeNumber(value):
    bus.write_byte(address, value)
    return -1

def readNumber():
    number = bus.read_byte(address)
    return number

while True:
    temp = readNumber()
    the_struct = struct.unpack('5h', temp)
    print(the_struct)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think serialization is the thing you want. Do note that the architectures are probably different enough to send raw memory (which would be a bad idea).

Comment: Okay thanks I'll look into serial communication.

Comment: that's not really what i meant, actually. i.e. [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-overview). serial communication maybe could be fine depending on your use though.

Comment: Ah okay, I started looking into that. It looks like the Wire.write function is able to send a byte array, which I've done. But now my problem is converting that byte array into an integer array on the Pi.

Comment: Both the RPi and Arduino uses little endianess, so i don't think there's any weird conversion to make sure of. You should explicitly give the size of Data, Data2, etc. to avoid any confusions - i.e. int16_t or int32_t, on both ends.

Comment: To read back the data on the RPi, you could do something bad and non-standard which is pointer aliasing with a different type, i.e. `reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(pointertochar)`, but you also need to enable a compiler flag - so it's not really a good idea. so the thing you can do is to have `int32_t integer = c1 << 24 | c2 << 16 | c3 << 8 | c4;` (replace c* by array accesses to the character array). Make sure you send the data to the rpi the same way.

Comment: I've also found struct.unpack and int.from_bytes functions but I don't understand how to use them. There are limited examples and the documentation is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Wire.write((byte *)&my, sizeof(my))` to write to the RPi. To read the data, you can unpack the struct into a tuple using the `struct` module like this:

```
import struct

#assuming you've recved the struct over I2C into a bytes object named 'data'
the_struct = struct.unpack('5h', data)
```

`the_struct` now holds the 5 integers in your original struct.

EDIT

Firstly, 0x04 is one of the reserved addresses. Try 0x15 instead; anything (almost) from 0x08 upwards will do.

You are reading a byte and then attempting to unpack that byte into 5 integers. You should instead read 10 bytes, save them one by one to a `bytearray` and then unpack them as shown earlier. Replace your `readNumber()` with this:

```
def read_block(num_bytes):
    vals = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, num_bytes)
    return vals

while True:
    temp = read_block(10)  # 10 is the number of bytes you want to read
    the_struct = struct.unpack('5h', temp)
    print(the_struct)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I've tried the Wire.write(&my, sizeof(my)) and get multiple errors. It seems my struct is of the wrong data type? However if I declare, for example, byte var = {1,2}, I can successfully pass it in with Wire.write(var, 2).

Comment: Thanks @TisteAndii I was able to get the data to write. Now

Comment: Now when I put 'the_struct = struct.unpack('5h', data)' in my Python code I get typeerror: 'int' does not support the buffer interface.

Comment: i forgot to mention : type punning is not only UB, but struct padding may also make the data sent unreliable! you should avoid this solution.

Comment: nevermind - it's actually legal to read a struct using an uint8_t*. but the padding is probably still an issue.

Comment: @Asu As long as he's using an 8-bit MCU like the one an Uno, padding is a non-issue.

Comment: yes, but it is still non-portable and fragile. if he ever wants to switch to, say an ARM Due, then this program will break.

Comment: The declarations are just for reference to remind me what the variables are. But I think I'm misunderstanding the rest of it. The way I interpreted it, Wire.write((byte *)&my, sizeof(my)) sends my struct of 5 variables through and is saved in my python code through temp = readNumber(). So temp should now hold the byte array of 5 values. From here I just need to unpack them correct? Unless I have it all wrong.

Comment: @Anthony `Wire.write()` *does* send all 5 integers but `readNumber()` a.k.a `bus.read_byte()` only reads one byte from the Arduino. The rest of the 9 bytes are ignored by the RPi. You need to use a different command. Check my edit.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't realize the bus.read_byte() only read a single byte. One more thing I don't understand is why I should use a 10 byte array if I'm only passing in 5 bytes?

Comment: @Anthony You are sending 5 *integers* and each `int` on an 8-bit MCU is 2 bytes in size. Did it work?

Comment: I seem to get errno 110 connection timed out

Comment: I've marked your post as the answer even though it hasn't completely solved my problem but it has been the most helpful so far. However I'm still struggling with the latest error of the connection timing out which seems to be caused by the bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, num_bytes) command.

Comment: @Anthony Can you still detect the Arduino on the I2C bus with `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`? Did you change the address like I said? Both in the Python code and in the Arduino code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126561/discussion-between-anthony-and-tisteandii).